# Why my X Server won't start as a regular user and it starts as Guest?

Tags: login-screen, users, xserver

It won't start X server automatically as a regular user but instead shows Logon screen. When I enter my password it flashes for a second and it's back to Logon screen again.
Then I tried to log in as Guest user and it all went well.
How can I fix this. Please help.

To answer guntbert's question: Sorry but I don't know how to copy ls -lA output here. But i think it has something to do with .Xauthotiry beacuase it started poping up this error in terminal "xauth: timeout in locking authority file".

Comment: Please open a virtual terminal CTRL+ALT+F1. Can you log in there (you will not see anything when you type your password)? If that succeeds please show us the output of `ls -lA` (edit your question to put it there).

Comment: how do i copy(or save) that log here? + updated(edited) my question.

Comment: When you run `ls -lA`, do you find `.Xauthority`?

Comment: Yes! the line below:

-rw------- 1 root root 163 Jan 16 21:37 .Xauthority

Comment: It seams . Xauthority was for some reason taken by root account (don't have clue why or how). What i did was:

Ctrl+Alt+F1 --> <code>sudo passwd</code> changed my password --> <code>sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg</code> to reinstall xorg --> <code>cd /home/{name}</code>to enter home folder(where .Xauthority is located --><code>sudo mv .Xauthority .XauthorityBak</code> to rename .Xauthority file. --> Restarted my machine and it worked. Thanks guys for your help anyway! plur

Answer (score 0):

> Ctrl+Alt+F1 --> `sudo passwd` changed my password -->
>
> `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg` to reinstall xorg
>   -->
>
> `cd /home/{name}`to enter home folder(where .Xauthority is
>   located -->
>
> `sudo mv .Xauthority .XauthorityBak`

From OP in comment.